how to read research paper word-by-word and comprehended it?
I know it has been related to other questions, but this is different angle.
I am a trying to read research papers more efficiently. Off course, I came to realize that large papers are not meant to be read word-by-word, but focusing on sections of interest.
However, even when try to follow my understanding sequence and read the parts I am interested at, I usually have difficulty in two particular things:

sometimes the paper uses too many jargon I am not familiar with, which would require me reading the same part multiple times, google and come back and so forth. Sometimes I don't even have the time to finish and understand an average size section because of that jumping between resources.
Explaining in the figure is usually done, but reading, especially online, makes it hard to keep the figure and text aligned. Even worse, some articles like in arxiv would have the figures 10s of pages away from the text. Again, hopping between paper is consuming and my attention span can't usually hold "what I was reading? what I was looking at?" cycle.

During my studies, many times I need to read 10 articles from start to finish in short period, these limitations makes it difficult for me.
One thing that mitigate that is printing out the articles and highlight and write definitions, but sometimes it is costly to print.
Is there are some pro tips for reading well for the internet?

I’m assuming, correctly or incorrectly, you’re mainly reading papers in English. Practice in reading and writing will build comprehension skills. I couldn’t tell you how to shortcut that.

"but reading, especially online, makes it hard to keep the figure and text aligned" Well, you can open the file twice to see both pages at the same time (preferably on a second screen, but if necessary it also works on a single screen).

If a paper uses too much jargon that you are not familiar with, then that is an indication that you are missing the background knowledge of the field that the paper assumes its readers will have.

What field are you in?

As @TobiasKildetoft says, you have not internalized enough background yet (it is a learning process) to quickly parse things. One does not read technical material word-by-word (or even reading children's stories aloud).

Is the language that you're reading in the same as your native language, or different?

First, I don't want to assume, but it's pretty clear English is not your native language and you might need practice in "regular" English. You might also try translations of article. Google Translate is free; it's far from perfect, but it has improved a lot in recent years, especially for relatively common languages.
Second, regarding figures, you can a) Print the figure (if you have access to a printer) b) Use two monitors (again, if you have that) c) Split your screen into windows (works best with a larger monitor). (You mention that it can be costly to print, but, if you just print the figures, you usually have relatively few pages).
